# Wordpress rewrite url not working

Tags: wordpress

I 've create the page `tag` with page id `3055` and slug `videos-tag`. I want to add another segment to the url for queries like `http://www.example.com/videos-tag/test` so i added a rewrite rule.

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%videos-tag%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_rule('^videos-tag/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=3055&q=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

When i click on this link `http://www.example.com/videos-tag/football`.  I get 404 error page not found?

How do i solve?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already add **[query_vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars)** on your function ? If so you can change your rewrite function become this code bellow

in this case I see your query parameter is 'q', try to something more unique ie : vidq or something else.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse12065_init' );
function wpse12065_init() { 
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'videos-tag(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?pagename=videos-tag&q=$matches[2]',
         'top'      
    );
}
```

PS : Don't forget to **save permalink**

reference URL = http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/